# How to translate "ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100" to systemd-networkd?

Tags: linux-networking, systemd-networkd

I am trying to setup a software router with the goal of routing packets to a proxy server on the router. The tutorial I am reading has the following routing rules:

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 table 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
```

and the following iptables rules:

```
iptables -t mangle -N V2RAY
iptables -t mangle -A V2RAY -d [Private Addresses] -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A V2RAY -p udp -j TPROXY --on-port 12345 --tproxy-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A V2RAY -p tcp -j TPROXY --on-port 12345 --tproxy-mark 1
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j V2RAY
```

The whole thing works perfectly. But now I am moving to use `systemd-networkd` to avoid any startup scripts, and I am having trouble to convert `ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100` to `systemd-networkd` language.

My first question is, what does this route do? My understanding so far is:

- `iptables` add a firewall wall mark 1.
- The rule selects all packets with mark 1 to use routing table 100.
- The route is added to table 100, so it only applies to packets with mark 1.
- The "0.0.0.0/0" part means it is a default route.
- But what does "local" mean here? Why `device lo`? Why do we need a route here? Can't iptables handle this directly?

My second question is how to do this in `systemd-networkd`.

For matching packets with mark 1, it seems easy (and worked on my router):

```
[Match]
Name = *

[RoutingPolicyRule]
FirewallMark = 1
Table = 100
```

I am not sure if `Name = *` is required though. Does this make sure that any packet from any device, as long as it has mark 1, will be routed using table 100? Or could I match some particular network device here?

I cannot, however, make the route in systemd-networkd. My attempt so far is:

```
[Match]
Name = lo

[Route]
Type = local
Destination = 0.0.0.0/0
Table = 100
```

But it seems that this has no effect: `ip route show table 100` actually gives:

```
Error: ipv4: FIB table does not exist.
Dump terminated
```

How should I approach this?

Comment: Your tutorial's contents come initially from this kernel documentation: https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/tproxy.txt . There should be better explanations about the "why" there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[Match]
Name = lo

[RoutingPolicyRule]
FirewallMark = 1
Table = 100
Priority = 100

[Route]
Table = 100 
Destination = 0.0.0.0/0
Type = local
```

Combine them into one file

Comment: Thanks! It wonderfully works!